# Adding odd numbers in an array not providing the correct output

Tags: arrays, ruby

one of my ruby programs that detects odd numbers in an array and adds them together does not provide the correct output. Given that I am learning ruby and this is a logic mistake, I can't easily deduct where I make a mistake.
Here is the Code:

```
def odd_sum(numbers)
  index = 0
  result = 0 
  while index < numbers.length
    if (numbers[index] % 2 != 0)
      result += 1
    end
    index +=1
    return result
  end
end  

puts odd_sum([1,2,4,5,7,9]) currently my output is 1 should be 22
puts odd_sum([0,6,4,4]) currently output 0
puts odd_sum([1,2,1]) currently output 1 should be 2
```

Question: Why is my output wrong? Any way to make this cleaner or better?
I'm running all this in a program called oddball.rb on cloud9.

Comment: Do mind your indentation, otherwise it's really hard to see where is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`return result` will cause the code to exit right then and there... it will only ever add up the first number, then exit the whole method forever... it will never look at the other elements of the array.

Having now indented your code properly you can see that this line is inside the while loop...
probably you want that to be outside the while loop... it is much easier to see this kind of bug when you properly indent your code. You should always indent your code... it seems unimportant until you come across a bug like this... it's always important. it's a good habit to start now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at your if-statement: result+=1, don't add 1 but add the the number you are currently testing: result += numbers[index]

SiS

Answer (score 1):

```
def odd_sum(numbers)
  index = 0
  result = 0 
  while index < numbers.length
    if (numbers[index] % 2 != 0)
      result += 1
    end
    index +=1
    return result
  end
end  

puts odd_sum([1,2,4,5,7,9]) currently my output is 1 should be 22
puts odd_sum([0,6,4,4]) currently output 0
puts odd_sum([1,2,1]) currently output 1 should be 2
```

On the line `result += 1`, you are adding `1` each time there is an odd number, so it's not a sum, but rather a count.

On the line `return result`, the program will immediately end when it hits the `return`. So, since the first number in the first array is odd, the program increments result by 1, and then returned result.

What you want to do is `result += numbers[index]`, and return the result at the end of the while loop.

In Ruby, there's often a better way to do things, while loops are meant for when you don't know how many times you are looping. In this case, you know exactly how many times, so I would suggest using an iterator.

```
def odd_sum(numbers)
  result = 0
  numbers.each do |num|
    result += num if num.odd?
  end
end
```

Or even better

```
def odd_sum(numbers)
  numbers.select(&:odd?).reduce(&:+)
end
```

Comment: My initial thought was that "or even better" was not better because it requires two passes through the array. After reflection, though, I agree with you because `select` and `reduce` are both written in C, so it's probably faster than your first method. Breaking it into two sequential operations also makes it easier to debug and test. Note you can write `.reduce(:+)`. (See the doc.)